# Update a row in a data extension where part of the primary key is a date field that defaulted to now

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, php

Is it possible to update a data extension row where part of its primary key is a date field that defaulted to now?

The problem I'm having is that if I did not specify the date when I created the record, I cannot update that record (I receive a concurrency violation saying 0 of 1 rows were updated).

However, if I create a record and explicitly provide the date, I can subsequently update that row. Unfortunately, I've got about 340,000 rows that were created using the default (now) for the date.

Comment: Are you talking about `CreationDate`? It could be send only during creation if you have right to do so.

Comment: Are you specifying both the all the primary key fields in you update statement?  I'm guessing the data value provided does not have the same  precision as the value stored in the data extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do a toolbar extract of the DE, strip the times and re-import the data -- assuming that will not violate the primary key.

You can also run an update Query Activity on the it that strips the time part off:

```
select
cast(y.createdDate as date) createdDate
from YOURDENAME y
```

You'll still have to deal with potential PK violations.

Comment: Casting worked, and I had to cast to a date (instead of datetime)--as I still had the problem casting to datetime. Our best guess is that the default timestamps might include milliseconds which aren't visible to us.